# volsnap: The shadow copies of volume C: were aborted because of an IO failure on volume C:

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, event-viewer, volume-shadow-copy

I have the following error appearing in Event Viewer several times per day:

```
The shadow copies of volume C: were aborted because of an IO failure on volume C:.

source: volsnap
```

Nothing found in web search for this message

Answer (score 6):

I'll show you bellow a possible way to fix this kind of error. I'm using Windows 7, but these instructions are valid for Windows 8, too.

1. As you can see in the *Administrative Events*, I have a lot of errors, so I'm starting to fix the first one, which is caused by the *VolSnap* source.

   [image]
2. First of all, you must have administrative rights, to get access to the *System protection* tab of the *System Properties* window:

   [image]

   [image]

   Just select your operating system drive letter, and press the *Configure* button, to open the *System Protection* window.
3. Looking at the *Disk Space Usage*, you'll see there is no space left for *Shadow copies* to function correctly.

   [image]
4. [System Restore might use between three and five percent of the space on each disk.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-much-disk-space-does-system-restore-require) Therefore, we need to move the slider to the right and to increase the disk space used by the system protection.

   [image]

   After pressing *Apply*, *OK* and then *restarting the computer*, everything will be just fine.

   A funny thing: in my case, all the other errors have disappeared, a sign that all of them were related to the first one.